# How to create a Supply & Demand style chart

Tags: spreadsheet, google-spreadsheets

Here's an example of a basic **Supply and Demand Graph**:

[image: Basic Supply & Demand Graph]

- The **Vertical Axis** is always *Price*
- The **Horizontal Axis** is always *Quantity*
- There should be two lines, one for the **supply curve** and one for the **demand curve,** both of which represent different quantities at a particular price.

Here's some [**sample data**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qxfxT55lpVl3dkaFk77CdtkBZezZR3ksXGZOFk9gw1s/edit?usp=sharing):

```
| P | Qty D | Qty S |
|---|-------|-------|
| 4 |    95 |    40 |
| 5 |    90 |    65 |
| 6 |    80 |    80 |
| 7 |    60 |    90 |
| 8 |    50 |   100 |
| 9 |    45 |   110 |
```

When I try to map this in Google sheets as a Line chart with two series, it keeps adding price as the X-axis because that's the shared variable between the two, **but price needs to be on the y-axis**.

**Sample Output** (axes backwards):
[image: Sample Output]

This [forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/tmoGKvvtfCY;context-place=topicsearchin/docs/category$3Afirefox) is asking the same question, but the links are dead

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that Google sheets requires a **shared X-Axis** for multiple series of data:

[image: Edit Data Series]

This is true even if you select [Combo Chart](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9142593#combo_chart) which just allows you to select multiple chart styes.

Since the Qty<sub>S</sub> & Qty<sub>D</sub> do not need to share identical data, we need to create one big, shared Quantity scale that merges all possible values and can be used by both.

To create a range of values, you just need to wrap a range in curly braces `{...}`.  To [flatten multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14151000/1366033), you can separate multiple ranges with a semicolon `;`.  Then `Unique` will strip out duplicates and `Sort` will put the remaining values in numerical order.  So we can create a combined set of values like this:

```
=Sort(Unique({A2:A7;B2:B7}))
```

Now we'll map the applicable data-points from each set of data onto the master quantity list with either a `VLookup` or `Index...Match`.  If we don't get a value, we'll just skip it with `IsError` like this:

```
=IfError(Index(A:C,Match(E2,A:A,0),3),"")
```

Combined, this should take the data set from above and return a usable format [like this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qxfxT55lpVl3dkaFk77CdtkBZezZR3ksXGZOFk9gw1s/edit?usp=sharing):

```
| Qty | Demand | Supply |
|-----|--------|--------|
|  40 |        |      4 |
|  45 |      9 |        |
|  50 |      8 |        |
|  60 |      7 |        |
|  65 |        |      5 |
|  80 |      6 |      6 |
|  90 |      5 |      7 |
|  95 |      4 |        |
| 100 |        |      8 |
| 110 |        |      9 |
```

Now we can easily create a chart with multiple series of data:

[image: Supply & Demand Fixed]

Comment: Well this certainly works, so thank you. But it's kind of crazy that Google forces us to jump through such hoops to get it working